# Android Studio - Can't load resource from some_lib.aar file located in the libs folder (or from the mipmap folder)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I searched about this issue and didn't find any answer that related to my problem yet. i hope someone handle this problem before and could help me (-:.

1. I have an android studio project that have inside the 'libs' folder an
   aar library (for example: some_lib.aar).
2. Inside the aar library i have the 'mipmap' and 'raw' folders that have 
   resources inside (The 'mipmap' has PNGs and the 'raw' has sound 
   file called: sound.wav).
3. In my project i'm trying to load some *.png file from the mipmap and 
   sound file from the 'raw' folder as follows:

---

```
Uri soundUri = loadSoundFromLocal(context, "sound.wav");
```

---

```
private Uri loadSoundFromLocal(Context context, String sound) {             

    try {

        // Get resource id.
        boolean isGmeResource = true;
        int soundResource = UtilsResources.getResId(sound, R.raw.class);
        if (soundResource == -1 || soundResource == 0) {

            soundResource = UtilsResources.getIdentifier(context, sound, "raw");
            if (soundResource != -1 && soundResource != 0) {
                isGmeResource = false;
            }
        }

        // Create the uri string for the sound file.
        if (soundResource == -1 || soundResource == 0) {

            return RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        } else {                                                    

            return UtilsResources.getUriFromResId(context, soundResource, isGmeResource);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static int getResId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(resourceName)) { return -1; }
    if (c == null) { return -1; }

    try {

        Field field = c.getField(resourceName);
        if (field == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return field.getInt(null);                      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static int getIdentifier(Context context, String name, String defType) {

    String appPackageName = UtilsData.getAppPackageName(context);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(appPackageName)) {            
        return -1;
    }

    if (context.getPackageManager() == null) { return -1; }     
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) { return -1; }     
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(defType)) { return -1; }

    try {

        Resources resources = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(appPackageName);
        if (resources == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return resources.getIdentifier(name, defType, appPackageName);      

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        // Should never happen
        UtilsLogger.e(LOG_TAG, (e != null)? e.getMessage() : "Could not get package name");
        return -1;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        UtilsLogger.e(LOG_TAG, (e != null)? e.getMessage() : "Could not get identifier version code");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

4. I have an exception like this (also for the 'mipmap' folder):

**THE EXCEPTION**:

```
Process: com.growmobile.engagement.sample, PID: 20883
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/growmobile/engagement/R$raw;
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.loadSoundFromLocal(ModelPushMessage.java:451)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.parseMessageData(ModelPushMessage.java:375)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.<init>(ModelPushMessage.java:174)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.buildPushMessageObjectAndSaveItToDB(ManagerNotification.java:139)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.buildGMENotificationObject(ManagerNotification.java:108)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.initializeNotification(ManagerNotification.java:77)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.executePushAction(GMEGcmListenerService.java:152)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.handleMessage(GMEGcmListenerService.java:118)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(GMEGcmListenerService.java:79)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.growmobile.engagement.R$raw" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.growmobile.engagement.sample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.growmobile.engagement.sample-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.loadSoundFromLocal(ModelPushMessage.java:451)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.parseMessageData(ModelPushMessage.java:375)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ModelPushMessage.<init>(ModelPushMessage.java:174)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.buildPushMessageObjectAndSaveItToDB(ManagerNotification.java:139)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.buildGMENotificationObject(ManagerNotification.java:108)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.ManagerNotification.initializeNotification(ManagerNotification.java:77)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.executePushAction(GMEGcmListenerService.java:152)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.handleMessage(GMEGcmListenerService.java:118)
        at com.growmobile.engagement.GMEGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(GMEGcmListenerService.java:79)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.growmobile.engagement.R$raw
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 18 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

---

- I must to say that when the library is imported as a module and not as 
  *.aar file everything working great!!!
- I need to import the library as *.aar file so I'm stuck and need a
  solution soon as possible!
- Is my code OK? if not, What is wrong here?

Thanks for advance for any help from anyone
hope i will get answer quickly (-: